# Give a reference of a text,pdf,anything , where geodesic passing by a certain point is calculated.

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, geodesic

I'm looking for a text , pdf , any reference , where it calculated in details geodesic passing by a certain point , for example on a surface of revolution.

Something in the type , a geodesic passing by (0,0,0) can be found doing ...
I'd like the expression to be given explicitely and not "left to the reader".

I'm trying to verify that i understand how to do it but i need to enter in calcul depths to check it.

Comment: I haven't thumbed through Spivak's tome *A comprehensive introduction to differential geometry* lately, but I would guess there are some such calculations therein.

Comment: In Euclidean space you are solving the second derivative is zero.

Comment: You will find some explicit examples in my differential geometry text, freely linked in my profile. There are also numerous exercises to do similar computations.

Comment: this https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1288&context=rhumj is good